# C++ Class Constructor Argument: How to access members and methods from another class instance without copying?

Tags: c++, eclipse, class, constructor

I have two classes `A` and `B`. In `A`, I have some members and some methods, e.g.,

Header Files:

A.hpp:

```
    class A {   
      public:
        A(int i);
        virtual ~A();
        int j;
        Eigen::Vector3d e;
        void printE();
    }
```

B.hpp:

```
class B
{
  public:
      B(A* A_ptr);
      virtual ~B();
      void doSomething();
  private:
      A * object;
};
```

Source Files:

A.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.hpp"
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

A::A(int i)
{
  j = i;
}
A::~A()
{
}
A::printE()
{
  cout<<"e = ("<<this->e(0)<<","<<this->e(1)<<","<<this->e(2)<<")"<<endl;
}
```

B.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

B::B(const A * A_ptr)
{
  object = A_ptr;
}
B::~B()
{
}
B::doSomething()
{
  int a = 2*object->j+object->e(1); // very stupid and simple example
}
```

}

In class `B`, I would like to access the members as well as the methods of an instance of `A`, without copying anything. I thought about passing a pointer to an instance of `A` to the constructor of `B` and to access the desired members and methods.,

This code above is just an abstraction of my problem, but I hope you get my point.
My code compiles fine (I use Eclipse Luna), except from when I try to create an instance of class `B`

```
#include "A.hpp"
#include "B.hpp"
using namespace Eigen;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  A A_instance(n);

  A* A_ptr;
  A_ptr = &A_instance;
  B B_instance(A_ptr); // commenting this line, the code compiles fine

  return 0;
}
```

When compiling this code, Eclipse outputs these errors:

```
Errors (3 items)
    make: *** [all] Error 2
    make[1]: *** [some_path.dir/all] Error 2
    make[2]: *** [some_other_path] Error 1
```

which unfortunately does not help me a lot.

My question is: Which is the best way to do this? Is it maybe better to use a friend class or inheritance? (Note that `A` makes some computations that are required for `B`, but otherwise they are not related.) Or am I doing something wrong when passing the pointer as an argument in the constructor of `B`?

Comment: You are using `ClassA` and `A`. Is that your actual code? Did you make an error in transcribing the code?

Comment: As is this example won't even compile as it has [many errors](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b1d3c84f84b1f269).  Please [edit] your question with an [MCVE (Minimal Complete Verifiable Example)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or [SSCCE (Short, Self Contained, Correct Example)](http://sscce.org)

Comment: Try to create "A" on the heap using new. A* A_ptr = new A

Comment: @RSahu no, as I stated in my post, this is of course not my actual code. Nevertheless, I have edited the code in the post s.t. it compiles.

Comment: Those errors make me think there might be something wrong with the project setup rather than (or maybe in addition to) the code. I don't think I've ever seen such useful errors from a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

```
void doSomethingB(A_ptr->a);
```

This is not a valid member function declaration nor definition.

You may want to write

```
void doSomethingB() {
    A_ptr->a; // what do you want to do with it?
}
```

Comment: you're right, thanks for the hint. Changed it accordingly in my post.